# custom class and size for the_post_thumbail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to resize a particular image on the fly with the_post_thumbnail() which I have done like so:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array (475, 317 ) ); ?>
```

This works in resizing the image to the specified size but I also want to add a class to this. If I try add a class then the size dimensions are still correct but it doesn't apply the class?

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array (475, 317, 'class' => 'border--round' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try To Use it Like This :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array (475, 317), [ 'class' => 'border--round' ] ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to customize "size, class etc" then you can use this function.

```
the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

ex: if you want to use img tag then the code will be like this.

```
<img class="yourclass" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( array(475, 317) );?>" alt=""/>
```